# Why is my AUv3 randomly disappearing with "viewServiceDidTerminateWithError"?

Tags: objective-c, audiounit, auv3

I’ve encountered a strange problem during iOS AUv3 Instrument development which I’m having trouble finding information on. I’ve spent a couple weeks now attempting to debug this, and I was wondering if anyone else has encountered it. It feels more like an "OS killed the app" than a crash, so I use the term crash loosely. Here are the symptoms:

- It doesn't seem to ever happen on initial instantiation; it's when a project is reloaded. But, you can comment out setFullState and it'll still occur.
- The “crash” is inconsistent. Like a lot of slippery bugs, it’ll start happening consistently and then it’ll stop happening completely.
  When it does happen, it initially appears to load fine: the view loads and looks correct, and it produces audio. But, after a couple seconds, the plugin view disappears and it stops producing audio. I see this in the console log:
  viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
- You don’t have to generate any MIDI events to crash it. It would crash even after I commented out the processing block.

If anyone has any ideas, including how to get some useful debugging info out of this situation, let me know!

- I tried to look at crash logs, but there are no crash logs generated
- didReceiveMemoryWarning is not tripped. In fact, I did an experiment where I allocated 100 megs and memset’d it on startup, and it didn’t crash it.
- I tried attaching a debugger, but it goes from “no debug session” to “waiting to attach” after it crashes-- at no point does it actually attach. It will attach if I then reload the plugin, but then it won’t crash. The Zombies and Leaks tools didn't reveal anything, nor did the memory sanitizers.
- Using a Storyboard instead of a XIB didn't change the behavior (not sure why it would, but it was one of the last few differences between this and Apple's example).

I created a very tiny example project which exhibits the problem (unfortunately, I cannot post any code which shows the problem because I cannot find where exactly the problem code is-- maybe it's even a project setting?). It has a minimal GUI, no setFullState, and generates white noise:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dw3xTHn3qY411eXLaIb_9_S5PAtrr5Nk

Expected: It doesn't crash or disappear randomly

Actual results: After reloading a project file which uses this AUv3, the plugin will disappear after a few seconds. It initially produces audio normally and the GUI looks OK, but then vanishes.